# The difference between running c++ programs with VS and VScode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

The following program runs completely differently on VS and VScode：

My VScode's configuration environment is MinGW.

I was able to run the correct result on VScode, but it was wrong on VS and

its output was problematic.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maxn = 101;
int visit[maxn][maxn];
//int mazeArr[maxn][maxn];
int stepArr[4][2] = { {-1,0}, {1,0}, {0,-1}, {0,1} };
int n;
int mazeArr[5][5] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0}
};

struct Node {
    int x;
    int y;
    int step;
    Node* parent;
    Node(int x1, int y1, int step1) :x(x1), y(y1), step(step1) {}
};
bool isVisited(vector<Node> closed, struct Node* b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < closed.size(); i++)
    {
        if (b->x == closed[i].x && b->y == closed[i].y)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void BFS()
{
    Node node(0, 0, 0);
    queue<Node> q;//open表,队列存储
    while (!q.empty())
        q.pop();
    q.push(node);
    vector<Node> visited;//closed表
    visited.push_back(node);
    Node target(n - 1, n - 1, 0);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        Node* p = &q.front();
        cout << "Node p的parent:" << p->parent << endl;
        //cout<<"q.front.x"<<q.front().x<< q.front().y <<endl;
        q.pop();
        if (p->x == n - 1 && p->y == n - 1)//若是到达终点
        {
            target.parent = p->parent;
            cout << "target.parent:" << target.parent << endl;
            target.x = p->x;
            target.y = p->y;
            cout << "step" << p->step << endl;
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int x = p->x + stepArr[i][0];
            int y = p->y + stepArr[i][1];
            Node next(x, y, p->step + 1);
            if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < n && y < n && !isVisited(visited, &next) && mazeArr[x][y] == 0)
            {
                //Node next(x, y, p.step+1);
                next.parent = p;
                //              cout<<"next的parent:"<<next.parent<<endl;
                visited.push_back(next);
                q.push(next);
                //              cout<<"q.front"<<q.front().x<< q.front().y <<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    //回溯路径
    Node* re = &target;
    vector<Node*> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        cout << "re:" << re->x << " " << re->y <<endl;
        result.push_back(re);
        re = re->parent;
    }
    //路径输出
    for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "(" << result[i]->x << "," << result[i]->y << ")" << " ";
    }
}
void main()
{
    n = 5;
    /*  int mazeArr[5][5] = {
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0}
        };*/
    if (mazeArr[0][0] == 1 || mazeArr[n - 1][n - 1] == 1)
    {
        cout << "无解";
        exit(1);
    }
    BFS();
    //DFS();
    system("pause");
}
```

This is the result of running on VScode：
(https://i.loli.net/2019/11/11/NaifV2YlhBcRGkW.png)

This is the result of running on VS：
(https://i.loli.net/2019/11/11/peEMkjOtgx72WvJ.jpg)

Since I can't use images because I don't have enough levels, I have to ask

the difference between the two compilers compiling c++ files.

Comment: `Node* p = &q.front(); q.pop();` invalidates `p`. Accessing memory pointed by `p` is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: `Node`'s constructor doesn't initialize `parent`. The program accesses this uninitialized member, which exhibits undefined behavior.